# Serializing a CookieManager/CookieStore

Tags: java, cookies

I'm making a Java program that accesses a website, which depends on handing out cookies so I can be logged in. I've found out that using a CookieManager will allow my URLConnection to atleast gather these cookies, but then how do I have these cookies persist when the java program is closed?

I already have a class that manages serialization of a few variables, so how can I implement cookies into this serialization process? Java apparently doesn't allow me to serialize CookieManagers and CookieStores by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend CookieManager and make it implement serializable. Then use the extended CookieManager you just created.

For example:

```
public class NewCookieManager extends CookieManager implements Serializable{
  //Code here...
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not very clear on what I have to do to make the CookieManager completely serializable. I have my new class extending CookieManager and implementing Serializable, but then what do I need to do? Right now, the cookie store from within is not retaining any cookies from previous run sessions.

Comment: Right, so it's the //Code here... part that I'm confused at. Is there some kind of reading material I should look at? I just don't understand why the cookies aren't being read back in properly. I don't want to change the functionality of CookieManager, just make it serializable.

Comment: Maybe it will be useful for someone. `org.apache.http.client.CookieStore` is an interface. It's default implementation is `BasicCookieStore` which is already implements `Serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cookie manager that keeps all cookie headers in a serializable map. You can call the `put` method to make it parse cookie headers again.

```
public class KeepHeadersCookieManager extends CookieManager {

    private Map<URI, Map<String, List<String>>> cookieHeaders = new HashMap<>();

    public KeepHeadersCookieManager() {
    }

    public KeepHeadersCookieManager(Map<URI, Map<String, List<String>>> cookieHeaders) throws IOException {
        for (URI u : cookieHeaders.keySet()) {
            put(u, cookieHeaders.get(u));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void put(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders) throws IOException {
        super.put(uri, responseHeaders);

        Map<String, List<String>> uriCookiesHeaders = cookieHeaders.computeIfAbsent(uri, u -> new HashMap<>());
        List<String> uriSetCookieHeaders = uriCookiesHeaders.computeIfAbsent("Set-Cookie", h -> new ArrayList<>());
        List<String> uriSetCookie2Headers = uriCookiesHeaders.computeIfAbsent("Set-Cookie2", h -> new ArrayList<>());
        List<String> setCookieHeaders = responseHeaders.getOrDefault("Set-Cookie", new ArrayList<>());
        List<String> setCookie2Headers = responseHeaders.getOrDefault("Set-Cookie2", new ArrayList<>());
        uriSetCookieHeaders.addAll(setCookieHeaders);
        uriSetCookie2Headers.addAll(setCookie2Headers);
    }

    public Map<URI, Map<String, List<String>>> getCookieHeaders() {
        return cookieHeaders;
    }
}
```

That way, you can call getCookieHeaders() to get a serializable map of all cookies headers, and pass it back to the constructor to initialize the cookie manager from a previous state.

Comment: Note that this is a rather dumb implementation. You may want to override cookies with the same name correctly.